# Need to use UTC timestamp conversion on in PHP/MySQL on a per connection basis

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I want to be independent from the timezone configured on a server so in a script I set the time zone like this:

```
mysql_query("SET time_zone = '".date_default_timezone_get()."';");
```

The server is currently configured to Europe/Moscow which currently is UTC+4

Then in a PHP site I select something from the database like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SET time_zone = '".date_default_timezone_get()."';");
$sth->execute();
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT  * from logs WHERE time like '2011-06-1%'");
$sth->execute();
```

I am using Timestamp field type and not Datetime.

Not what I get displayed is a timestamp that is 2 hours too far in the future.

The mysql doc says:

> Values for TIMESTAMP columns are
>   converted from the current time zone
>   to UTC for storage, and from UTC to
>   the current time zone for retrieval.

So this brings me to the 3 possible cases:

- Storage conversion works, select does not: No - because then The timestamp would be 2 (or 1 in winter) hours too far in the past
- Storage conversion does not work, but select does: No - because then i would see UTC which is -1 hours which is not the case
- Storage conversion doesn't work, select conversion doesn't work: Looks just like it!

Now the timestamp I write into the database is constructed and written PHP side:

```
$hourprec = "Y-m-d H:00:00";
$hour = date($hourprec); // mysql compatible
...
REPLACE INTO logs (time,...) VALUES('".$hour."','"....
```

I can imagine that this makes problems with mysqls time conversion because it comes as a string and I should do FROM_UNIXTIME or something.

But shouldn't it work at least with the select then?

Am I missing something? How do I have to do it if I want to store and read timestamps correctly in UTC in a mysql database but read/write them in scripts that have different time zones?

Comment: and please dont ask why i use a mixture of mysql and pdo and prepared statments without params xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was quite trivial.

The approach above is just fine, MySql just didn't know ANY timezones.

You can test this with the command `SET time_zone =  'UTC';`

If you have the same problem as the questioner you should recieve the following error:

```
#1298 - Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'UTC'
```

This can be easily fixed with the following command:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo/|mysql -u root mysql -p
```